# Does 'mixing' the result of a 32-bit hash to create a 64-bit hash have any value?

Tags: hash

For example, if you're programming in Java, and you want to create a 64-bit hash function for an arbitrary object, does it make sense to apply something like murmurHash3's 'finalizer' to the result of Object.hashCode()?

Specifically, is the following hash function

```
long Mix(int i)
{
    long result = i;
    return result ^ (result << 32) ^ (result << 33); // Or some 'better' way of mixing up the bits of i.
}

long Hash(Object o)
{
    return Mix(o.hashCode());
}
```

better than simply doing

```
long Hash(Object o)
{
    return o.hashCode();
}
```

(I'm well aware that the second one gives you nothing over a 32-bit hash)

The hash is going to be used to implement (recursive) hash-join, and the buckets are going to be determined by doing `hash % prime`. A concern is that it's going to be hard to make a good sequence of independent hash functions for the 'recursive' part if we only have 32-bits to start out with.

I'm thinking the answer is 'no', and that you really need to start out with a 64-bit hash which was computed directly from the value of the object.

I guess a side question is whether you actually need a 64-bit hash in the first place for the purposes of hash-join.

Comment: Well, two 32-bit values are either identical, or they are not. You can't make them more identical than identical :) The best possible 32-bit (or longer) hash of a 32-bit value is the value itself.

Comment: You don't _need_ a hash to do a join - using a hash table is just one way - you can also create a join by using nested loops, for example. But especially for complex keys, hash joins can often be quite efficient compared to the alternatives.

Comment: Yes, we will have a fallback to nested loop, but most descriptions of hash join talk about doing a recursive hash join with a different hash function in the case where the bucket gets too large, so that's what we were thinking about.